# Pass arraylist with bundle

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this

```
class Message implements Serializable
{
    public String message, sender;
    public Message (String msg, String from)
    {
        // check here that msg and from are not null. If so, use a default value or throw an NullPointerException
        message = msg;
        sender = from;
    }
    // Just a utility method for printing out the Message to System.out
    public String toString () { return sender+":"+message; }
}
```

I am defining this variable in main activity

```
Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>>();
table.get(room_name).add(new Message("Hi", "Sender"));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("messages", table.get(sendTo));
```

And in fragment I am getting this data with this code

```
ArrayList<Message> extractedMessages = (ArrayList<Message>)getArguments().getSerializable("messages");
System.out.println(extractedMessages.size());
```

But my app is crashing,I am getting java nullpointer exception for `extractedMessages.size()`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution is** ::

```
Bundle.putParcelable/Bundle.getParcelable
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784231/how-to-pass-custom-object-in-bundle).

- Use those methods, `putParcelable` and `getParcelable`.

---

**Also you can** ::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActity.class);
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("arraylist",myArrayList);  //myArrayList is ArrayList<Integer>
startActivity(intent);
```

***To get the arrayList in second Activity.***

```
ArrayList arrayList<Integer> = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("myArrayList")
```

---

### {Edit} ---- You can use newInstance to pass the data from fragment to fragment

***This is one of the way to achieve it, i use constructor to pass the data***

**FragmentOne.java**

```
int myData=12;
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment frgObj=FragmentTwo.newInstance(myData);
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, frgObj,"FragmentTwo");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
int myData;
public static FragmentTwo newInstance(int _myData){
FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
myData=_myData
return  fragment;
}
```

---

### {EDIT-3}

I have made a project for you [download it from Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/to8r1bjxofnnz0f/ScreenNavigation.rar)

- Mount in in your editor and run it .... it has bunch of other stuffs
  .... don't bother about it
- Check how i am `starting a fragment from activity` ----> then
  `onClick` of button how i am `starting a fragment` ---> there pass
  the data with the constructor as i shown in `edit2`

**[`ALSO REFER -- this -- StackOVERFLOW POST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784231/how-to-pass-custom-object-in-bundle)**

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: But this is not a activity I am using fragments.

Comment: You are using fragment ? .... ok .... check my edit .... i have passed the integer similarly you can pass arraylist too ... simple !

Comment: @Tolgay Toklar .... download the project from my `edit3` and learn how to use `newInstance` .... let me know if you are able to resolve it !

Comment: I think I can't do it.Is there another way to pass custom arraylist ?

Comment: using newInstance is the simplest way , ...else you have to perform interfragmentcommunication...pass data from fragmenta--->activity ----> fragmentb ... check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDHnIZEJ76I ........... my way is very simpler !

Comment: But I am using tab system,and I don't want to change my methods.Did you look my code ? Can I implement your code to my code ?

Comment: Yes you can ! ... using `newinstance` is just using constructor to pass the data ... try some sample examples on using `newinstance` ... my download link project has  all you need ....

Comment: I tried now,but not worked,I could pass the list to another fragment but I am still can't using size function.