# Saving the instance of Recycler view during orientation change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, orientation-changes, onconfigurationchanged, scroll-position

I have a `RecyclerView` which was build using an `Arraylist`. That `Arraylist` consists of User defined objects named `ListItem`.

Each `recyclerview` has a card view. Each `CardView` holds each `ListItem`.
I have removed one `CardView` from that `RecyclerView`.

When I rotate the screen , A new Activity is created which results in showing the old data. But I want the `recyclerview` to hold only `updated list` and should `retain` the `scrolled position`.

*ListItem class* :

```
class ListItem(var title: String, var info: String,  val imageResource: Int) { 

}
```

*MainActivity class* :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mSportsData: ArrayList<ListItem>
    private lateinit var mAdapter: MyAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val gridColumnCount = resources.getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,gridColumnCount)
        mSportsData = ArrayList()
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
        initializeData()
        recycler_view.adapter = mAdapter

        var swipeDirs = 0
        if (gridColumnCount <= 1) {
            swipeDirs = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        }

        val helper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT or ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,swipeDirs) {
            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                val from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val to = target.adapterPosition
                Collections.swap(mSportsData,from,to)
                mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from,to)
                return true
            }
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                mSportsData.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
            }
        })
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
    }

    private fun initializeData() {
        val sportsList : Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.sports_titles)
        Log.d("Printing","$sportsList")
        val sportsInfo : Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.sports_info)
        val sportsImageResources : TypedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sports_images)

        mSportsData.clear()

        for (i in sportsList.indices-1) {
            Log.d("Printing","${sportsList[i]},${sportsInfo[i]},${sportsImageResources.getResourceId(i,0)}")
            mSportsData.add(ListItem(sportsList[i], sportsInfo[i], sportsImageResources.getResourceId(i, 0)))
        }
        sportsImageResources.recycle()
        mAdapter = MyAdapter(mSportsData,this)
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun resetSports(view: View) {
        initializeData()
    }
}
```

*MyAdapter class* :

```
class MyAdapter(var mSportsData: ArrayList<ListItem>, var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item,parent,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = mSportsData.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val listItem = mSportsData.get(position)
        holder.bindTo(listItem)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            val currentSport = mSportsData.get(adapterPosition)
            val detailIntent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
            detailIntent.putExtra("title", currentSport.title)
            detailIntent.putExtra("image_resource", currentSport.imageResource)
            context.startActivity(detailIntent)
        }
        fun bindTo(currentSport : ListItem){
            itemView.heading_textview.setText(currentSport.title)
            itemView.description_textview.setText(currentSport.info)
            Glide.with(context).load(currentSport.imageResource).into(itemView.image_view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like initializeData is called twice since onCreate is called again on orientation change, you could use some boolean to check if data has been already initialized then skip initializing

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict activity restarting in your Manifest if you have same layout for Portrait and Landscape mode.

Add this to your activity in the manifest.

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

If you don't want to restrict screen orientation changes, then you can use `OnSaveInstanceState` method to save your older data when orientation changed. Whatever data you save via this method you will receive it in your `OnCreate` Method in `bundle`. Here is the helping [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662482/5701085). So here as you have `ArrayList` of your own class type you also need to use [Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252048/5701085) or [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) to put your ArrayList in your Bundle.

Except these making `ArrayList` as `public static` is always a solution, But its not a good solution in Object Oriented paratime. It can also give you `NullPointerException` or loss of data, in case of low memory conditions.

Comment: I have Different UI design for portrait and landscape . While using this, when I change the screen from landscape to potrait , the same UI design which is in landscape is applied for portrait also .

Comment: if it helps, please accept my answer. or let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are deleting the values that are passed down to the recyclerview but when the orientation changes the recyclerview reloads from activity and the original data from activity is passed down again and nothing changes, so if you want to save the changes in recyclerview you have to change the original data in the activity so that if the view reloads the data is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think u initialize adapter in oncreate method in which the whole adapter will be recreated and all datas is also newly created when configuration changes. Because u init data in oncreate method. Try something globally maintain the list and also delete the item in the list in activity when u delete in adapter also. Or try something like view model architecture

Answer (score 0):

Use `MVVM` pattern in the project. It will manage the orientation state.

MVVM RecyclerView example:
https://medium.com/@Varnit/android-data-binding-with-recycler-views-and-mvvm-a-clean-coding-approach-c5eaf3cf3d72