# FragmentTwo cannot be cast to FragmentOne when I am trying to comunicate between fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I have two fragments and I want to show them in my screen one by one. They are managed by MainActivity. The first fragment contains a TextView and a Button. The second fragment contains an EditText and a Button. What I am trying to do is: The first fragment shows on screen, and when the user press the button I want my activity to show the second fragment, and when the user press the button from this fragment I want to send the text from the EditText to the first fragment and display it on the TextView. I used interface for listeners.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Listener, ListenerTwo{

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, new FragmentOne());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}

@Override
public void onButtonSelected() {
    fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, new FragmentTwo());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onButtonPressed(String text) {
    FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder);

    if (fragmentOne != null)
        fragmentOne.setTextt(text);
}
```

}

In my FragmentOne:

```
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Listener listener = (Listener) getActivity();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onButtonSelected();
        }
    });

}

public void setTextt (String text) {
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

In FragmentTwo:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ListenerTwo listener = (ListenerTwo) getActivity();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onButtonPressed(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: maybe you should consider using `ViewModel` ?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace exception

Comment: Process: ro.scoalainformala.fragments, PID: 10116
    java.lang.ClassCastException: ro.scoalainformala.fragments.FragmentTwo cannot be cast to ro.scoalainformala.fragments.FragmentOne
        at ro.scoalainformala.fragments.MainActivity.onButtonPressed(MainActivity.java:34)
        at ro.scoalainformala.fragments.FragmentTwo$1.onClick(FragmentTwo.java:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)

Comment: Why you expecting that `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder)` would return instance of `FragmentOne` when you first replace it with `FragmentTwo` ?

Comment: `FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder);` This must return fragmentTwo, because it is the current fragment in the placeholder

Comment: Should I replace first with FragmentOne and then call setTextt?

Comment: Yes you should do the transaction first

Comment: Why do you think that you can use view of the fragment which is after `onViewDestroyed` in its lifecycle ?

Comment: '    public void onButtonPressed(String text) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, new FragmentOne());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder);

        if (fragmentOne != null)
            fragmentOne.setTextt(text);
    }'

Comment: Now I have another error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `Activity` in `onButtonPressed` method you are casting currently set `FragmentTwo` to `FragmentOne`. note that whe you are setting `Fragment` you are using `fragmentTransaction.replace(` <- REPLACE! you are loading fragments into `R.id.fragmentPlaceholder`, when new one is set, then previous is going to be destroyed

inside `onButtonPressed` you have to set again `FragmentOne`

```
fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, new FragmentOne());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

these lines are common, are placed also in `onCreate` so they may be packed into one method called in these two places

for transfering some data into fragment you may use passing this object in a constructor, but better way would be to use [`Bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment), so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showFragmentOne(null);
}

@Override
public void onButtonPressed(String text) {
    showFragmentOne(text);
}

private void showFragmentOne(String text) {
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
    if (text!=null){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("text", text);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

inside `onViewCreated` at the end of method check `Bundle` and set text

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    String text = bundle.getString("text", null);
    if(text!=null) setTextt(text); // or just textView.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: you still have wrong line there, casting to `FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne)getSupportFragmentManager()`...

Comment: added snippet in my answer, there is also solution under linked stackoverflow topic

Comment: If I would like to transfer an object how would I do?

Comment: I've already answered your question, it was about `String`. I'm not your personal trainer, if you have any other question start new topic or just search, [answer is already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784231/how-to-pass-custom-object-in-bundle/46591617)