# Is it possible to send an arrayList of arrayLists from one activity to another in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this arrayList: `public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ejemplo=new ArrayList<>();` and I´d like to send it to another activity in my project but I don´t know how.
I have read that there is: `intent.putStringArrayListExtra();` but it is to send an arrayList and in my case if I use that it says that it´s expecting an `arrayList<String>` and I´m providing an
`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.
Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: you can convert it to a serializeable object and then pass it along.

Comment: And how is that? Sorry, but I don´t know a lot about java

Comment: maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252048/3900210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your arrayList of arrayLists into jason, then pass the string to the other activity.  Then in the activity, decode the json into your object.  Check out the [Gson library from google](https://github.com/google/gson).